# Module build failed babel-loader Unexpected token "<"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

There are a seemingly endless number of questions here and on github asking this question and none of the solutions work for me. I'm simply trying to update an old project and I'm consistently getting this error:

`Module build failed (from ../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):`

`SyntaxError: /Users/user/Documents/project/src/index.js: Unexpected token (5:16)`

The unexpected token is "<" `ReactDOM.render("<"App />, ...);`

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.3",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
  "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
  ...
}
```

webpack config: (webpack 4.43.0)

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
    },
  ...
  ],
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
"presets": [
  "@babel/preset-env",
  "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

For context, the old babel packages work just fine.

Are there any other solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty standard. Had an issue after upgrading from v6 t v7 of babel , had to switch from .babelrc to config file which cleared the cached files. For quick trial you can add this in webpack and try

```
loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets:["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react" ]
            },
```